# Is it possible to change cursor icon while dragging, with HTML5 native drag and drop

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the native HTML5 drag & drop and I'm trying to change the cursor icon while dragging.

I noticed while dragging that there are only 2 types of icons. 
First is when you move item over dropable area (default cursor with small rectangle at the bottom ) and when you are not over that kind of area (forbidden icon)

Is it possible to change the cursor icons? For example I want hand cursor while I'm over droppable area. Also I read about **DataTransfer.dropEffect** and **DataTransfer.effectAllowed**, but neither of these solved my issue.

Also it is not CSS issue because I try

```
* {cursor: crosshair!important}
```

and there was no effect, the cursor did not change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the cursor to something like the [grabbing cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Values) but instead are limited to [predefined dropEffects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect#Syntax) like copy, move and link.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
:global {
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
    cursor: url('./assets/cursors/grabbing.cur'), move !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Nope, it looks it is not css issue. it aint work event with :global